# Kendo UI: error when executing the controller

Tags: zend-framework, namespaces, kendo-ui

i get the error:`Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1` when executing a controller using KENDO UI to generate graphs & containing syntax like this: `$valueAxis = new \Kendo\Dataviz\UI\ChartValueAxisItem();` I found that it s a php version error, that the versions lower than 5.3 doesn t support namespaces, but i m running PHP 5.4 with zend framework 1.12.3 & i still have this error.

Controller:

```
 class StatsController extends Oft_Controller_Action

{
function init ()
{
 require_once 'library/Kendo/Autoload.php';

}

public function indexAction(){



    $india = new \Kendo\Dataviz\UI\ChartSeriesItem();
    $india->name('India')
          ->data(array(3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855));

    $valueAxis = new \Kendo\Dataviz\UI\ChartValueAxisItem();

    $valueAxis->labels(array('format' => '{0}%'))
              ->line(array('visible' => false))
              ->axisCrossingValue(-10);

    $categoryAxis = new \Kendo\Dataviz\UI\ChartCategoryAxisItem();
    $categoryAxis->categories(array(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011))
                 ->majorGridLines(array('visible' => false));

    $tooltip = new \Kendo\Dataviz\UI\ChartTooltip();
    $tooltip->visible(true)
            ->format('{0}%')
            ->template('#= series.name #: #= value #');

    $chart = new \Kendo\Dataviz\UI\Chart('chart');
    $chart->title(array('text' => 'Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/'))
          ->legend(array('position' => 'bottom'))
          ->addSeriesItem($india)
          ->addValueAxisItem($valueAxis)
          ->addCategoryAxisItem($categoryAxis)
          ->tooltip($tooltip)
          ->seriesDefaults(array('type' => 'line'));

    echo $chart->render();


    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I can't help you, but it may help if you edit your question to show some actual code (Javascript, Controller).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP is on your server?

The basic requirements for Kendo UI PHP Wrappers is 4.3.

Try this out!